# Why am I seeing ads when my reputation is over 1000?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, advertising

Is this a bug in Stack Overflow? Why am I seeing this ad when my reputation is over 1000?

[image]

Comment: Alex why did you approve a wrong edit?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ads are only *reduced* once you hit 200 reputation. They are not eliminated completely. The [privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) specifically defines which ads are removed:

> After you achieve this privilege, the two "leaderboard" style ads will be automatically suppressed from question pages when you are logged in.
>
> [image: ads image]
>
> The areas in red are the leaderboard ads. The areas in gray are the sidebar ads, which will remain visible.

Your screenshot is showing a sidebar ad next to the question list (one of the gray ones in the above sample). These ads are not suppressed by your rep.